# Cleanly Passing a Dependency Using Smart Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I am in the early stages of learning "modern" C++ and would like to ask what the "best-practice" is for providing a dependency to a consumer whilst using smart pointers for management.

I would like it to be the case that a change to the object state referenced by the smart pointer, is reflected in the consumer class.

I also don't want the consumer class to know about the smart pointer as I feel this makes the interface/constructor less clear. However maybe this is misinformed?

The example below does what I want using aliases, but is it the "right" way to achieve my goals using "modern" C++? Are there alternative approaches / idioms I could be aware of?

**Header**

```
class Widget {
public:
    int cost { 0 };
    virtual ~Widget();
};

class WidgetConsumer {
public:
    Widget& _widget;
    explicit WidgetConsumer(Widget&  widget);
    virtual ~WidgetConsumer();
};
```

**Source**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "widgets.h"

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Widget> widgetB = std::make_unique<Widget>();
    WidgetConsumer widgetConsumerB(*widgetB);
    widgetB->cost = 23;
    std::cout << "widget.cost=" << widgetB->cost << std::endl;
    std::cout << "widgetConsumer._widget.cost=" << widgetConsumerB._widget.cost << std::endl;
}

WidgetConsumer::WidgetConsumer(Widget &widget) : _widget(widget) {
}

WidgetConsumer::~WidgetConsumer() {
    std::cout << "WidgetConsumer destroyed" << std::endl;
}

Widget::~Widget() {
    std::cout << "Widget destroyed" << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**

```
widget.cost=23
widgetConsumer._widget.cost=23
WidgetConsumer destroyed
Widget destroyed
```

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain." -- Scotty, Star Trek III. The end result of all this infrastructure: if the owning `unique_ptr` goes out of scope and gets destroyed before the `WidgetConsumer` is finished doing whatever it needs to do with its non-owning reference, then all sort of [vile demons will fly out of everyone's noses](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). In general, it's better to place less emphasis on Buzzword Bingo, and more emphasis on learning and understanding, so one can make an intelligent decision themselves.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so are you suggesting that good practice would be to pass by move the unique_ptr into the consumer once constructed so that the consumer has a member of type unique_ptr<Widget>?

Comment: The problem is that if you ask ten C++ developers whether "X" or "Y" is "good practice" you are guaranteed to get at least eleven different answers. Rather than worrying what is or isn't "good practice", it's more important to understand how ***everything works***, so, with the full understanding of all core C++ fundamental concepts one can make an intelligent decision, for their specific application, as to what is the best approach to the task at hand. There is no Central C++ Committee, of some kind, that sits and passes judgement of what is or isn't "good practice".

Comment: @Scruffers Smart pointers express ownership.  To decide where the smart pointer(s) go, you need to decide who owns the `Widget`.  If the caller owns the `Widget` (that is, its lifetime is tied to the object/scope that creates the `WidgetConsumer`) then pass a raw pointer or reference.  If the `WidgetConsumer` owns the `Widget` then pass a `unique_ptr`.  If both need the caller and the `WidgetConsumer` need to own the `Widget` then pass a `shared_ptr` (don't cheat and use `shared_ptr` as a bandaid for not understanding the ownership semantics of your program).

Comment: Thank you @MilesBudnek, that's extremely informative to someone just getting to grips with this. Appreciate it.